# DIBSection not rendering in Release mode

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I know when something work in debug but not in release, there's something not initialised, used or cleaned correctly, but I don't find what.

I first create a dib section like that:

```
BITMAPINFO bmi;
HBITMAP bitmap;
LPBYTE pBits;

// Initialize header to 0s.
ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(bmi));

// Fill out the fields you care about.
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = w;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = h;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

HDC dc = GetDC(hw); 
bitmap = CreateDIBSection(dc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&pBits, NULL, 0);

for (int y = 0; y < w*h; y++)
{
    pBits[y * 3 + 0] = 200;
    pBits[y * 3 + 1] = 200;
    pBits[y * 3 + 2] = 200;
}
```

Then I render it like that:

```
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP oldBmp= (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, bitmap);

BitBlt(hdc, xabs, yabs, width, height,
    hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBmp);

DeleteDC(hdcMem);
```

In Debug mode everything renders well but in release the image is white.
Also if I use `bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(idb), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);` the image is rendered correctly.

Comment: Improve your error checking so you know *exactly* which function failed.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help **must** include the desired behavior *and* the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please read how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code by calling it from WM_TIMER and later WM_PAINT handler and I can't reproduce wrong behavior win Release builds. Tested VS 2013, 2008 and even 6.0 but only on Windows 10.

I see problems (but they don't cause descibed difference between build modes).

- You get device context with `HDC dc = GetDC(hw);`, but there is no `ReleaseDC`.
- I don't know your value of `w` or `width`. You will have some visual glitches if it is not multiple of 4 for 24 bits mode.

In my testing code I have to guess few values (`xabs`, `yabs`). Check that you initialize them correctly.

```
void TEST( HWND hwnd )
{
    RECT    rect;
    GetClientRect( hwnd, &rect );

    int width = rect.right;
    int height = rect.bottom;
    if ( width < 1 || height < 1 )
        return;

    // width correction, up to muliple of 4.
    width = ( width + 3 ) & ~3;

    int xabs = 0;
    int yabs = 0;

    BITMAPINFO bmi;
    HBITMAP bitmap;
    LPBYTE pBits;

    // Initialize header to 0s.
    ZeroMemory(&bmi, sizeof(bmi));

    // Fill out the fields you care about.
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    if ( hdc == 0 )
        return;
    bitmap = CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&pBits, NULL, 0);
    if ( bitmap == 0 )
    {
        ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc)
        return;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < width*height; y++)
    {
        // Use more interesting visual.
        pBits[y * 3 + 0] = y/width; //200;
        pBits[y * 3 + 1] = 200;
        pBits[y * 3 + 2] = 200;
    }

    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    if ( hdcMem )
    {
        HBITMAP oldBmp= (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, bitmap);

        BitBlt(hdc, xabs, yabs, width, height,
            hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBmp);
        DeleteObject( bitmap );

        DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    }
    // Release device - missing in oryginal code.
    ReleaseDC(hwnd,hdc);
}
```